# Managing Laravel migrations in Git branches

Tags: git, migration, branch

In my Git repo I have two main branches, *master* and *develop*. Then from *develop* I make more branches when developing new features. Once I am finished with developing I merge *develop* into *master* and deploy. In Git I also keep track of my db migrations.

Now my issue is I had to make some hot-fixes in *master* which involved db schema modifications (= migrations). So I find myself having a db structure in production (*master*) and a different structure in development (*develop*), and some migrations <strike>from *develop* which should be injected before the last migrations in *master*</strike> from *master* which should be injected before the last migrations in *develop*.

One more thing is I guess *rollbacks* shouldn't be applied in production (one could lose production data).

I will find a way out from this situation but I wonder if there is a standard approach to managing such scenarios, especially when you have an app in production.

**Update:**

I think the next step should be rebase develop onto master, thus including *master hot-fix migrations* into *develop* as they were made before any work on the *develop* branch.

This brings out 2 problems:

1. I have several branches departing from develop which I don't know how to rebase in one go onto *master* (if it's even possible)
2. Laravel migrations in *master hot-fix* (created after some migrations in *develop* had already been created) will have timestamps which come after the ones in the *develop* branches, so I am not confident *develop* migrations will even get executed if I already played the *master* ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may branch out from master. Let's call it BugFix Branch.

1. Fix your bug in BugFix Branch
2. Use git cherry-pick command to only pick commits in BugFix that you want to involve into master branch.
3. Lastly, you may rebase or merge with developer branch as you wish.

Hope this helps. Leave a comment if anything goes wrong. Ready to help.

Comment: Thx Ray, I updated my question as the description was incorrect.